# Upload VS solution with multiple projects to webserver

Tags: asp.net, upload, ftp, designer

I'm trying to upload my visual studio solution to my webhost but I'm running into some problems.

When I run my site offline everything works perfectly, but when I try to access my website online, thing break.

This is my structure offline

[image: Offline structure]

And this is the structure after I uploaded it to my host (via filezilla) (and opened it in VS)
[image: Online structure]

I notice immediately that the .designer.cs files aren't correctly linked to their respective .aspx and .cs file. 
How did this happen because I uploaded every single file in my solution to my host?

I guess this is also the cause of these issue I get when I try to access the site
[image: Parser error]

Help and advice would be very appreciated!

Comment: Why would you upload the source code of the entire solution?! .NET web projects do not work that way. You need to reference the required projects to the web project and then compile it and make a deployment package. You need to upload the deployment package only, no source code or solutions at all.

Comment: The other 3 project contains my 3-tier layers so how do I include those? I don't have access to the IIS control panel

Comment: Your web project should reference your other projects. Once you build your web project, the other projects will also be built to dll-s and then they will be copied to the bin folder of the web project. When you prepare the deployment package, they will be included there. You do not need to upload anything else besides the deployment package. I am sure there are plenty of tutorials on how to do this in google and MSDN, as I fear StackOverflow is not the right place for that.

Comment: Oh, like that! I'm now currently publishing my site using a tutorial. Things are looking pretty good at the moment. Thanks!